# Pipeline did not respond within the appropriate time

Tags: search, crawling

I can't get the search to work, someone has an idea of what may be the cause?
On the crawl log, I see this message.
Errors: 3056 "pipeline did not respond within the appropriate time"
Success: 12

Those 12 items successfully crawled are top level pages from my site.
The other 3k errors are in majority list items, for example:
http://myintranet.corp/Lists/MyList/DispForm.aspx?ID=22

I've already reset the index and started a full crawl.
I'v checked the permissions of the user running noderunner.exe.
I tried increasing the timeout values of the Farm-search to 120s.

Don't know what else I can do... anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
Mainly this blog post was used: http://community.netapp.com/t5/Technology/Best-Practices-for-SharePoint-2013-Search-Service-Application-for-SMSP/ba-p/84062

We had to recreate the topology, index and everything again, but at this time we stopped the distributed cache service, killed the noderunner from the task-manager and removed the memory limit from its config file, then we did do recreated everything according to this blog post.